# animation frozen blend tree

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, mixamo

so I was gonna make my first third person rpg game and im a pretty experienced game developer around 3 years still when it comes to animations my brain stops functioning correctly so I made my own rigged player model with blender and mixamo.

I was gonna swap out the model from the third person starter asset thing because making 3rd person character controllers is insanely hard and I swapped out the player model on the geometry empty with my model and I setup the animation stuff and to be clear I used the starter asset animation controller and the animations and set the model to humanoid so when I hit play all it did is stay on the first frame of the idle animation for the starter asset controller like this
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/919670012028002357/1026996721127018607/unknown.png
you can still move run and jump it just stays solid the entire time, really weird issue.

I can send you my project files at any time if you need them.

there is my rig that came out of mixamo
https://www.mediafire.com/file/gusbnjhy7w4xu1o/sickplayerrig.fbx/file
have a good day please put down your suggestions even if you have a feeling they arent right

Comment: _Boss-sized paragraph hits you for 20 damage! You are dead.  Play again?_  Welcome to SO.  Consider re-formatting your post to include punctuation including multiple paragraphs.  This will help us help you.  Good luck!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: it now has grammar